# HAProxy + Websockets + Application Persistence

Tags: websocket, haproxy

I have a scenario that requires all websocket requests from a single browser to be routed to the same application server. Currently I am using HAProxy for the LB. I have noticed that it works great for 'normal' HTTP requests, but when I try a WebSocket request the sticky cookie is not inserted into the response. I have not yet dove into the source for HAProxy, but what appears to be happening is that HAProxy doesn't inject the cookies for 101 Switching Protocol responses? This is just a guess.

Here is my setup:
Browser < -- > Stunnel < -- > HAProxy < --- > 2 Node.js Servers

My HAProxy config:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1   local0 debug
  maxconn 4096
  #debug
  #quiet
  user haproxy
  group haproxy

defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  retries 3
  timeout client 50s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 50s
  option dontlognull
  option httplog
  option redispatch
  option logasap
  option http-server-close
  balance  roundrobin

# Set up application listeners here.

listen admin
  bind 0.0.0.0:22002
  mode http
  stats uri /

frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:8080
  default_backend servers-http
  capture cookie SSNID len 63


backend servers-http
   cookie SSNID insert nocache
   server 03PM1 127.0.0.1:8081 cookie 03PM1 check
   server 03PM2 127.0.0.1:8082 cookie 03PM2 check
```

Note, I tried 1.5 to see if it was 1.4, but no dice. I also eliminated the stunnel in front to see if was maybe something with SSL. Now time to dive into the source ...

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I did some digging and found out that there is a line of code in the HAProxy source that prevents injecting persistence cookies into the HTTP response for responses with an HTTP status code less than 200. This is an issue for WebSockets since the typical server response in the HTTP handshake is '101 Switching Protocols'. I posted some questions to the HAProxy forum here: http://marc.info/?l=haproxy&m=140853225609985&w=2

I don't believe this is really a bug given that the HTTP RFC indicates that 1xx response header fields are optional. But I do think there might need to be an update given the recent popularity of WebSockets. Depending upon the forum response, and if they give me the green light, I will submit my changes to the project at which point I will update this post.

**UPDATE:**
I submitted some changes to the HAProxy 1.6 master and they should be pulled in soon. The owner of the project (Willy) added a few changes to my original change and I have tested them in my environment. If the changes to 1.6 prove to be valuable and do not have any issues it is my understanding that they will be pulled back to versions 1.5 and maybe 1.4. You can see the email exchange here: http://marc.info/?l=haproxy&m=141080115708515&w=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the comments above you will see that the issue is the HAProxy code itself. It was skipping the header mangling on status codes below 200. This won't work for WebSockets as they use 101 in the handshake. Version 1.6 of HAProxy should have the changes soon (as of 9/15/2015).

I answered this question rather than relying on the edits above since it may not be clear there is an answer and I wouldn't want someone to think there was no activity on this front and waste a bunch of time.